# Reading csv file in R

Tags: r, csv

I read my csv file in R using

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv",header = FALSE)
```

What I get is

```
name place    phone #
sam  london   5343234
     NA       NA
jim  USA      4325235
john USA      NA
     NA       NA
```

How to remove the row with NA.These NA appear because I had a excel file in which there were spaces and I saved that file as csv.I want to generalize this code so the spaces could appear anywhere.So how to clean this up?

Comment: Did you try `na.omit(data)`? Or `data[complete.cases(data), ]`?

Comment: yeah It removes all the rows with NA value but I need some rows with missing values.Like john USA NA row will be omitted but I need that row

Comment: What do you want replace them with? You can try `data[sapply(data, is.na)] <- ""` for example. It will replaces `NA`s with `""`

Comment: After that how to remove empty row?

Comment: @sameedhayat including `blank.lines.skip=TRUE` in your `read.csv` could be a possible solution (see my answer)

Comment: After you read it as Jaap suggested, you can remove the remaining `NA`s with `data[sapply(data, is.na)] <- ""`

Answer (score 0):

As the `NA`-values appear to be blank lines, you might try:

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv", header=FALSE, blank.lines.skip=TRUE)
```